# Do something if :update actually writes anything

Tags: vim

I have a function in vim that is calling `update` and I'd like to call `execute` to run something in case the buffer was actually modified and written to the disk.

So I'm wondering if there's some sort of return value from `update` to indicate that, or some other way to know (`BufWritePost` seems to trigger only when `:w` is called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BufWritePost and BufWriteCmd are triggered just fine when I issued

```
:update
```

on my gVim 7.3 (WinXP). The autocommand fired when the buffer was actually modified, and didn't if it wasn't modified.

Tested with

```
:au!
:au BufWriteCmd *.cpp echo "bufwriteCmd called"
```

and

```
:au!
:au BufWritePost *.cpp echo "bufwritePost called"
```

Comment: This is strange. If I call `update` explicitly it works, but I have a `au CursorMoved *.tex silent update` that fails to trigger the BufWritePost.